# How to keep absolute positioned element on the screen when resizing

Tags: html, css

I've got a custom dropdown similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/hsmishka/54t32vfc/2/.
How do I keep the absolutely positioned dropdown on the screen when resizing the window?
Something like right: 0; but only when it doesn't fit the window.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div>
.outer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background: #EEE;
}

li {
    background: grey;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the outer tag needs to be absolute as well because it is wrapping the dropdown tag. Try that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end goal is.  But what you probably need is some media queries.  Really I would recommend checking out Bootstrap as it is build for responsive design.

But to get what you want working, you need to make sure the drop down parent is set to:

```
position: relative;
```

Then your drop down will be constrained to the parent.  Otherwise it will be to the body or whatever the nearest relative element is.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54t32vfc/3/)

```
Position:fixed; right:0;
```

It's worked.